# facebook application for only one user

Tags: facebook, share

I have a Facebook application to share content from website to Facebook groups, I want it to be accessible only by a specific user which is the admin of the website, and no one else but him can access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During authentification, get the Uid of the user, if it doesn't match the Uid of the admin, return 0.

Just one if, and one else...